# How to update mysql database value from java netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

How to update mysql database value from java netbeans
I need to update one of my selected column value
this table has 6 column but I need to update one column only (6th column)
So how to do this -

I use this code -

```
connectDB();
    try{

        String value1 = txt_searchcode.getText();
        String value6 = Final_stock_view.getText();

        String sql = "Update tbl_codes set No='"+value1+"',Bin_Balance='"+value6+"'WHERE No='"+value1+"' ";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your new records Updated Succsessfully!!");

    }catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Update Failed");
    }

    closeDB();
```

its running well without any errors, but nothing happen
So how to fix this...... (Examples)
Thanks

Comment: executes without problems? doubt it. you need spaces between your values and sql keywords.
before trying to execute the statement, print your sql String, copy that result in mysql and try to run it there.

Comment: Also, you're completely missing the point of prepared statements, which is to safely pass parameters to the query. Read the tutorial again. And please, please, respect the Java naming conventions, and choose much better names than value1 and value6 for your variables.

Comment: may be you are updating the record which does not exist. in that case mysql does not throw any error

Comment: can you please examples...